# How to write regex in a sequelize.js field validation.isIn.args

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I had wrote two regex in isIn.args, i want the `phone` validator can check my input value is one of these, but failed.

```
var ValidateMe = sequelize.define('Foo', {
    phone: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(20),
        validate: {
            isIn: {
                args: [[
                    // moible number of china
                    /^(13|14|15|17|18)\d{9}$/i,
                    // telphone number of china
                    /^((\(\d{2,3}\))|(\d{3}\-)|(\d{3}))?(\(0\d{2,3}\)|0\d{2,3}-)?[1-9]\d{6,7}(\-\d{1,4})?$/i
                ]],
                msg: "moible or telphone number format error!"
            }  
        }
    }
})
```

I want get the result:

```
var inputNumber = '15208282123'; // or '8008123'
( /^(13|14|15|17|18)\d{9}$/i.test(inputNumber) 
  || /^((\(\d{2,3}\))|(\d{3}\-)|(\d{3}))?(\(0\d{2,3}\)|0\d{2,3}-)?[1-9]\d{6,7}(\-\d{1,4})?$/i.test(inputNumber)
) === true;
```

Run it in the browser console, result is `true`.

Comment: do you mind clarifying what is the pattern you are trying to look for ?

Comment: this pattern is used to verify whether it is the telphone number or mobile number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sequelize "isIn" validator doesn't provide regex support, it checks weather value is directly present in the list of args or not, instead "is" validator supports regex, but i don't think it will support more than one regex at a time, you need to either convert 2 reg ex into 1 or create custom validator which checks both the regex and return true if one of them is passed, something like below

```
var ValidateMe = sequelize.define('Foo', {
    phone: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(20),
        validate: {
            validatePhone: function(value) {
               if(!/^(13|14|15|17|18)\d{9}$/i.test(value) && !/^((\(\d{2,3}\))|(\d{3}\-)|(\d{3}))?(\(0\d{2,3}\)|0\d{2,3}-)?[1-9]\d{6,7}(\-\d{1,4})?$/i.test(value)) {
                  throw new Error('phone format error!')
               }
            }
        }
    }
})
```